# Do design of a VHDL module as APB Master has any practical difficulty?

Tags: vhdl, memory

I went across VHDL codes for memory architectures, which contains modules designed as AHB masters, AHB slaves, Bridge, and APB slaves. But no APB slaves. Is there is any specific reason for excluding this module or I is just because design is not requiring a APB master ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through many online documents. What I understood from that is APB has no masters. Bridge between AHB and APB act as master for APB peripherals and Slave for AHB peripherals.

Comment: Yeah. Normally APB is used underneath AHB. If you were using APB on its own (eg with another processor) you would need to write an APB master : you could use the AHB/APB bridge as a pattern.